# How to convert vector at access to operator [ ] access in vim

Tags: c++, vim

Suppose I want to convert

```
var.at(i*w+j) = something;
```

into

```
var[i*w+j] = something;
```

What is the correct command to type in vim? I attempted

```
:%s/\.at\(.*\)/[\1]/g
```

which results in

```
var[(i*w+j) = something;]
```

works but it will be even better if the parentheses can be removed.

EDIT: showing correct resulting attempt

Comment: Wouldn't that substitution give you `var[(i+w+j) = something]`? `.*` is greedy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a recursive macro:

```
qqqqq/\.at(<CR>%"adi)F.c%[<Esc>"apa]<Esc>@qq@q
```

Explanation:

```
qq                                                   record macro `q`
  q                                                  end empty macro
   qq                                                record macro `q`
      /\.at(<CR>                                     search for `.at(`
                %                                    go to the matching closing `)`
                 "adi)                               delete inside the parenthesis into register `a`
                      F.                             go back to the previous `.`
                        c%                           change what’s in the matching parenthesis
                          [<Esc>                     with `[` and leave insert mode
                                "ap                  paste what’s in register `a`
                                   a]<Esc>           append `]` and leave insert mode
                                          @q         call the (currently empty) `q` macro recursively
                                            q        end macro
                                             @q      call the (now non-empty) macro `q`
```

This also handle stuff like `var.at(foo(bar, baz)) = something;` correctly.

Comment: Wow, but I tried typing this and it shows `E486: Pattern not found: \.at(<CR>%"adi)F.c%[<Esc>"apa]<Esc>@qq@q`. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: `<CR>` means Enter, `<Esc>` means Escape

Answer (score 2):

> What is the correct command to type in vim? I attempted
>
> ```
> :%s/\.at\(.*\)/[\1]/g
> ```

The problem is that you're escaping the parens.  Due to your ["magic"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) settings, `\(` and `\)` work for grouping, whereas you want to match literal `(` and `)`

```
 :%s/\.at(\(.*\))/[\1]/g
```

works for me.   (Note that you still need the grouping)

Comment: I just realized that this won't work with the case of `something = var1.at(i*w+j) + var2.at(i*w+j)` typing your command will become `something = var1[i*w+j) + var2.at(i*w+j]` Could you let me know how to solve it?

Comment: Basically the issue is that .* is greedily matching as much as it can.  You can replace `.*` with `[^)]*` (match everything except a paren) to get around the problem

Comment: or use the ugly ungreedy, `.\{-}`

Comment: This works, but another more harder scenario is `something = var1.at((i+1)*w+j) + var2.at(i*w+j)`, which breaks it. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this case?

Comment: You can do one level of parenthesis explicitly with something like `%s/\.at(\(\(([^)]*)\|[^)]\)*\))/[\1]/g`, but trying to go any deeper runs into fundamental limitations of regular expressions fairly quickly.  You might be able to do something different if all of your cases follow another pattern (no spaces inside the at() parens, and always a space or semi-colon afterwards), but without something convenient like that, you've probably reached the end of what can be done with a simple regex. (and macros start to look much more helpful)